# errors while deploying sql server compact 3.5 sp2 privately

Tags: deployment, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

So Ive spent quite some time today with sql lite and saw the .net4 providers were very un stable. So I figured I'll use SqlCE. Its supposed to have a *zero config/install* instead its the most confusing way to deploy the thing.

I check numerous SO questions and these articles:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160128003045/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/22/privately-deploying-sql-server-compact-with-the-ado-net-entity-provider.aspx)

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150916191654/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/05/12/troubleshooting-problem-with-private-deployment-of-sql-server-compact-3-5sp2-entity-dll.aspx)

A More updated short guide:
http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-deploy-the-sqlserver-compact-edition-software-locally/

So here is my problem, without the `<runtime>` tag bit, it WORKS on my DEV machine but NOT on XPSp3 without the SqlCE runtimes. It gives me a `FileIOLoadException`

WITH the `<runtime`> tag it works on XpSp3 but on my dev box it says :

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.50, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation/2542055#2542055) but Im VERY confused. Also, apparently the msdn blog articles are off, you need to include 7 dlls all together. And the `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll` and `System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll` both come from folder named "Private" where the runtimes are installed.

```
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5"></remove>
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" 
           invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" 
           description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
           type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SqlServerCe" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.1.0-3.5.1.50" newVersion="3.5.1.50"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

*How in the world is this zero configuration!?* I have no idea what really is going wrong nor what I did to make it right? Isn't there documentation on this anywhere Other than some old blogs?

**Just simply put, once I need to deploy, I just want to be able to xcopy exe and other files and it should work.So where is the reference/msdn/documentation/step-by-step on how to deploy?**

**Also sqlce will work on a box with ONLY .net4 installed right?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a very similar problem posted on S.O. in [6851346](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851346), and I just solved it.

I don't know if you are still struggling with this, but I found a solution on Code Project called [Creating a Private Installation for SQL Compact](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLCEPrivateInstallation.aspx) that fixed my problems right up.

I hope this helps others, too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Entity Framework? If not, the runtime tag is not required.

You must change this:  Version=3.5.1.0 (in the add tag) to 3.5.1.50, and make sure you use the System.data.SqlServerCe.dll from the Private folder (it has this special assembly version)