# Strange Exception when using Entity Framework with SQLCE

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have used before EF 4 and SQLCE with no such problem.

While I have my assembly containing the edmx file and the context self tracking template and in another assembly the self tracking entities, I keep this strange compile error but the project compiles successfully...

```
Error   1   Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.
```

This just dont go away....but the program runs.

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem too, did you get any chance solving this issue? If so please share your solution. Thanks .)

Comment: Hello, have you fixed this issue? I can't seem to find any solution to this, I'm also having the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have done these....i have used the same approach in another project without this annoying problem....the thing is that the app runs smoothly:P