# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: .net, wpf, sql-server-ce

I have built a wpf application that is using EF and SQLCE4.

Everything works fine on my local dev machine however when I package it up and install on a test machine I keep getting this error

> Inner Expection System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
>      at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)

I have installed the SQLCE4 application and both .net4 client & extended frameworks.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Check weather this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation/2542055#2542055) on stackoverflow gives any insight to your problem.

Comment: Thanks Sascha, This was the problem. I would vote this as the answer but its only a comment.

Comment: Thats OK I guess - after all someone else really did answer it. And I did gain something as I did learn something useful myself.

Comment: @Sascha: Create a new answer or edit the existing (deleted) one with an answer that contains some content that targets this specific question. It is okay to cite another SO answer, but do provide more than just a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NuGet package manager 1.5 (for VS 2010 SP1) and download the SQL CE 4 package first.

And then add the package to you project, and rebuild it.

For info about SQL Server CE 4's Nuget:
http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/SqlServerCompact

On using Nuget: http://docs.nuget.org/