# SqlServer CE 4 Unable to find the requested .Net framework data provider

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I created a winforms app with Sqlserver ce 4.0.

I am using nuget to get the sqlserver ce 4.0 package.

After I compiled, I will get all the sqlserverce dll ready for me to distribute.

The files are:
System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll
amd64
x86

But I get this error:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net framework data provider
```

Thank you.

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation/2542055#2542055

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding the following block to application config file:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```