# The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid

Tags: entity-framework, exception, sql-server-ce, syntax-error

i use entity framwork with SQL Server CE 3.5 and i have this error

**The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.**

```
<Schema Namespace="OimDBModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" ProviderManifestToken="3.5" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="OimDBModelStoreContainer">
      <EntitySet Name="OfflineMessages" EntityType="OimDBModel.Store.OfflineMessages" store:Type="Tables" />
    </EntityContainer>
  </Schema></edmx:StorageModels>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2542055/1099260) answer to create a local copy of all the required Sql CE 3.5 assemblies. That should solve your problem