# Running C# application to client PC giving ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I am trying to run my C# application on client PC with new build but Instant Client is installed on it. In my application, I am accessing the database to retrieve some record to display. When I try to run the application on my development PC it works fine, but on client PC it shows me following Error:
**The store provider cannot found in configuration or is invalid**

My app.congif contains following:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StorageEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StorageModel.csdl|res://*/StorageModel.ssdl|res://*/StorageModel.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=myData;PASSWORD=myPass;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=myUser&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226842/the-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found-in-the-configuration-or-is-not-val) help?

Comment: I am unable to install this on client PC at the moment. Access rights issue..

Comment: I used TNS names in my connection string, I wonder if this is the issue as client PC may not understand this ??

Comment: Are you missing Oracle ADO.NET provider on the client machine?

Comment: ADO.NET is also installed but still same error - Store Provider is missing

Answer (score 0):

Is EntityFramework installed on the client machine ?

Comment: .Netframework and Instant Client is installed on client PC nothing else..Do I need to install anything else on client PC ? I am new in C# development..

Comment: Install Microsoft Process Monitor tool (it is free) configure it to capture all file access events of your application on the computer were the problem occurs, then look at the file access errors in the tool.

Comment: I installed win32_11gR2_client from Oracle website on client PC but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Process Monitor tool (it is free) configure it to capture all file access events of your application on the computer were the problem occurs, then look at the file access errors in the tool.

Here is a link to Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx