# Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in configuration - Sql Server CE

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

oI am building a WPF application in .net 4.0.
I have a local DB `.sdf` file. I am using EF to connect to the DB.
When building the application I get `Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in configuration`

I tried droping and recreating both the model and the sdf file.
I tried everything detailed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation/2542055#2542055) link and the blog post it was taken from.

I cannot get this error to go away. The application runs on my machine (The error is in the `edmx` file, so it still runs), but when I publish it and run the installer on another computer, I get the same error in a messagebox.

My local machine is Windows 2008 R2 64bit with VS2010 installed. The machine I'm installing on is Windows 7 32bit.

**Edit:** Also tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326(v=vs.100).aspx) and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I donwloaded SQL Server CE again and did a repair install, then reopned VS2010, did a build and the error went away.

I uninstalled and reinstalled and it didn't help, so I don't really know why this did, but there you go.

Comment: It added entries to your machine.config file dbProviders section.

Comment: @ErikEJ - The entries were there before. I checked. In fact, I copied from there to my app.config.