# Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid with EF4 and SQL Server CE 4

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to update project that makes use of an SQL Server Compact 4.0 database file, using standard SQL statements to insert/query etc, to use Entity Framework 4 (using VS2010 and .NET 4, so can't use a higher EF)

Since VS2010 doesn't have design time support for From Database Entity Framework configuration with SQL Server Compact 4.0, I followed the instructions posted by ErikEJ http://erikej.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html

Specifically the part about creating a schema exactly the same as the 4.0 version, using that to set up your entities, then pointing your configuration at the 4.0 provider and database.

After updating the `app.config` and `.edmx` files to point at 4.0 (as stated in the article), I get an

> Error 175: The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid

After reading more about the error, I came across this answer:
[Using Entity Framework with an SQL Compact Private Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540784/using-entity-framework-with-an-sql-compact-private-installation)

So I added:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" 
             invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" 
             description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" 
             type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

to my `app.config`, but this made no difference.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install my free SQL Server Compact Toolbox Visual Studio extension, connect to the database and use the "Generate Code" => "Add Entity Data Model to Current Project" feature

Comment: Perfect! Works great now. Thanks Erik!